# What operation is done by this macro?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

```
#define MS(_v, _f) (((_v) & _f##_MASK) >> _f##_LSB)
```

This macro is defined in `drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/core.h`.

Comment: Looks like "most significant" (MS) byte.

Answer (score 4):

`_v` gives an expression evaluating to a **v** alue (of a register) and `_f` names a **f** ield. The macro expands to an expression which bitwise-ANDs (&) the value with the mask named by `FIELD_MASK`, then right-shifts by `FIELD_LSB` to right-justify it.

In other words, it unpacks a bitfield.

Comment: what does this "_f##_LSB" and "_f##_MASK" mean ?
Yes, you told that its _fFIELD_MASK and _fFIELD_LSB  ?

But what about the syntax, what is the ## doing, and what does it mean ?

Comment: @BeagleBone That is the token concatenation operator. It splices tokens together.